# matlab reading a binary file

Tags: matlab, binary, fread

This is suppose of be very simple but I just can't get it right, probably because I don't understand something very basic.

I'm trying to figure out how to read a binary file into matlab which consists of 7 variables, each variable is written in 2 bytes (Hi and low). the first byte is MSB and others LSB.
The thing is that I'm aware of fread function, but I never seem to know how to use it right when a multiple varibales are involved (just a vector of numbers of the same type are easy) so if some of you could just explain in a word or two I would be greatful.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to call `fread` twice, specifying time by time which format you are using (either big-endian or little-endian).

```
 first = fread(fileID, 1, 'int16', 0 , 'b'); %big endian
 last =  fread(fileID, 7, 'int16', 0 , 'l'); %little endian
```

You have also to be specific with respect to the *value type* of the variable stored. You say that you have 2 bytes variables, they can be `'int16'`, for instance. Consider the reference of [fread](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) for the possible value types with 2 bytes.

Comment: Thanks Acorbe, the thing is this information I don't have so I have to guess, by evaluating the results. I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: [here](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) is the reference. My suggestion: try to read the first variable first. The types of variables featuring 2 bytes are not a lot.

Comment: Or simply call `fread` once, and then swap the byte values of the first variable.

Comment: @slayton, you're right, there are not 2byte floating point variables, thus the swapping is pretty easy.